# can't include Qt classes while creating project with VS-add in

Tags: c++, qt

I recently begin to use Qt and decided to use it with Visual Studio (2013).
The problem is that when i create the project the Qt classes even the most common can't be included (as QApplication) even if i had to it every Modules (core GUI...). Intellisense underline it in red saying :"cannot open source file QApplication". And when i try to run the project, it tells me that i missed some .dll. The weirdest thing is that i already manage (2 times) to make it worked, simply by creating the project without doing anything special(i think).
Moreover when i use the qtcreator it works fine but i'd like to use VS. 
Sorry, i had a hard time being specific since i really don't have a clue.

Comment: It looks like you did not add Qt to your include and library paths. I am not sure if that is needed. I don't use the addon for that. I generate my Qt project files in Visual Studio using CMake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition @drescherjm comment, you should also check that you have an system environment variable set - The variable name should be QTDIR and the path should be the path of your installation - on my system this is C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\msvc2013.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it seems i found a way to resolve the problem but i still don't get why.
It appears that if i go in the Qt options even if the path is already set, i need to select it and press ok. And then build the project and reopen it for intelisense to work. And it worked. But it's weird because i already fund the place where the qtdir variable is stored and it was alright but the project still didn't worked??